# How to reference CloudFormationProvisionedProduct Outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to provision AWS resources via AWS Service Catalog. I have a 'product' which i can provision and then i need to reference some property available in Outputs of provisioned product resource.

I wanted to reference the value within Outputs of AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct and hoped that it works same way as Outputs of a stack.
I tried !GetAtt http:// ProvisionedProductName, Outputs.InnerProperty - did not work, i get Requested attribute Outputs.InnerProperty must be a readonly property in schema for AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct

The Outputs attribute exists, however i am not sure how to explode this list and get an inner property.
I tried to use !Select to reference a list item, however it does not seem to work either:
!Select [1, !GetAtt https://forums.aws.amazon.com/

Template error:
Fn::Select requires a
list argument with two
elements: an integer
index and a list
Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently launched this exact feature, so "!GetAtt YOURPROVISIONEDPRODUCTNAME.Outputs.YOUROUTPUTNAME" should work.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/provisioned-product-outputs-now-available-aws-service-catalog/

This blog was updated too: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-launch-secure-and-governed-aws-resources-with-aws-cloudformation-and-aws-service-catalog/, search for ".Outputs."

Comment: Actually, I am seeing the same problem.  When using the returned output.  I am seeing "...must be a readonly property in schema".  This is very recent.  I have had it work before.  This started in the last few days.  I am following this thread to see if anyone else is seeing this.

Comment: You're right, I got the same error when I tried after posting, but now it's working again.

Comment: Yeah, same here.  Now it is working.  Guessing AWS had an Oooopppsss moment.