# Expose SNSTopic TopicArn in AWS CloudFormation Template: How might I expose my TopicArn in my CloudFormation script for my SNS Topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, aws-service-catalog

I'd like to expose the TopicArn Value (referenced in the outputs section at the bottom of my code snippet) of my SNStopic via Cloudformation template in the outputs tab of my stack in a similar manner to the way it's exposed in the resources when I create an SNStopic through the service catalog. I tried to access it by referencing it in the outputs section of my yaml script using dot notation but have been unsuccessful thus far. How might I be able to do so? I'm looking to do this so others using my script in the future won't have to go searching for the TopicArn in another place in order to subscribe to it.

Another important thing to note is that the provisioned product id below, under the properties section of the resources code block generates an SNSTopic.

```
Resources:

  LabTrainingSnsTopic:
    Type: "AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct"
    Properties:
      ProductId: prod-4iafsjovqrsrm # Sns Topic 
      ProvisioningArtifactName: "v1.1" # Must be an actual version number. 
      ProvisionedProductName: !Ref ProvisionedProductName
...
Outputs:

AccountID:
  Description: The account in which this was built.
  Value: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
TopicArn:
  Description: Arn of the topic we created
  Value: !GetAtt LabTrainingHigSnsTopic.ProvisionedProductName.Resources.SNSTopic
```

[service catalog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKebs.png)
[cloudformation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix31E.png)

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070205/how-to-reference-cloudformationprovisionedproduct-outputs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference CloudFormationProvisionedProduct Outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070205/how-to-reference-cloudformationprovisionedproduct-outputs)